# Install OpenCL on Ubuntu 17.04, intel

Tags: 17.04, opencl

Install OpenCL on Ubuntu 17.04, Intel

I'm trying to install OpenCL on ubuntu 17.04
with:

```
$ lshw :

     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2899MHz
          capacity: 3100MHz
          width: 64 bits

        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:34 memory:a0000000-a03fffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

So far, haven't been able to find any docs.  Intel's "install.sh" reports unsupported OS.

---- As per @Thomas, I've installed: `apt-get install beignet clinfo`

So far there does not seem to be opencl gpu support

Here is the clinfo output:

```
$ clinfo :



Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.11
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can install `beignet` package for use with Intel, and `clinfo` will be helpful to check what is recognized.

```
apt-get install beignet clinfo
```

Then run `clinfo` to check the openCL devices.

```
clinfo
```

Depending on your plans, you also might want to have to install development packages or other libraries as well.

```
apt-get install beignet-dev
```

For libraries or programmes you are interested in use the command as follows to find them.

```
apt-cache search opencl
```

Comment: revised question with clinfo output.  This doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: beignet is only for intel GPUs and doesn't enable OCL for CPU compute.