# DaVinci Resolve 15 doesn't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, video, startup, crash

I have problem with DaVinci Resolve 15. After installation app doesn't start. I use makeresolvedeb_15.0b6 to make .deb package. Logs:

```
#TIME Sat Jul 21 12:15:20 2018 - Uptime 00:00:01 (hh:mm:ss)
#PROGRAM_NAME DaVinci Resolve v15.0.0b.065 (Linux/Clang) 
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x3ef09e9]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve(_ZN7BtDebug14ReportSegfaultEiP7siginfoPv+0x6c) [0x3eeffec]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f7f335a3890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f7f315c4e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f7f315c6801]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x939c) [0x7f7f4b25639c]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x94c6) [0x7f7f4b2564c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22036) [0x7f7f4b26f036]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x223a1) [0x7f7f4b26f3a1]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x228f7) [0x7f7f4b26f8f7]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(__gxx_personality_v0+0x6c) [0x7f7f4b26fddc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1(_Unwind_RaiseException+0x14b) [0x7f7f31987b6b]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(__cxa_throw+0x66) [0x7f7f4b26e9c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x92f034]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x92e829]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x9268fa]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8f053c]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8edd7e]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8ec935]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8ec218]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x928343]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve(_ZN7BtDebug14ReportSegfaultEiP7siginfoPv+0x4d7) [0x3ef0457]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f7f335a3890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f7f315c4e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f7f315c6801]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x939c) [0x7f7f4b25639c]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x94c6) [0x7f7f4b2564c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22036) [0x7f7f4b26f036]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x223a1) [0x7f7f4b26f3a1]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x228f7) [0x7f7f4b26f8f7]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(__gxx_personality_v0+0x6c) [0x7f7f4b26fddc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1(_Unwind_RaiseException+0x14b) [0x7f7f31987b6b]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(__cxa_throw+0x66) [0x7f7f4b26e9c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x92f034]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x92e829]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x9268fa]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8f053c]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8edd7e]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8ec935]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x8ec218]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve() [0x928343]
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve(_ZN7BtDebug14ReportSegfaultEiP7siginfoPv+0x4d7) [0x3ef0457]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f7f335a3890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f7f315c4e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f7f315c6801]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x939c) [0x7f7f4b25639c]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x94c6) [0x7f7f4b2564c6]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22036) [0x7f7f4b26f036]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x223a1) [0x7f7f4b26f3a1]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x228f7) [0x7f7f4b26f8f7]
Signal Number = 6

================================
[0x7f7f29bd8480] | Main                 | INFO  | 2018-07-21 12:15:20,369 | Updating display GPU information...
OpenCL error -1001, GPUPropertiesUtilUnix.cpp:338.
terminating


My soft: Ubuntu 18.04
My device: Dell XPS 13
Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) 
Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
16 GB RAM
```

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately I am not able to provide a solution. But maybe I can share some insight. I also tried to install DaVinci Resolve (DaVinci_Resolve_15.0b7_Linux) today on an almost identical system (Lubuntu 18.04, same CPU, same Graphics, same Memory, but an HP) and had the same error.
I believe that our Graphics is just not good enough for Resolve. If you check their forum you will find them saying again and again that Resolve requires a good GPU.

I got a step further by installing OpenCL with the following command:

```
apt-get install beignet clinfo
```

and then checking with:

```
clinfo
```

(see also: [Install OpenCL on Ubuntu 17.04, intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952164/install-opencl-on-ubuntu-17-04-intel#952183))

This solved the above error and the welcome screen of DaVinci Resolve was showing. But then I still got the error message, that no OpenCL capable GPU was found.
[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYcC1.png)

Some comments on the DaVinci forum also mention, that even if you get Resolve starting up with this kind of low-end GPU, you will not be able to work properly with it...

Comment: Thank you. Now I have the same error like you. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe it would require a better GPU to work. Which is a bit problematic with a notebook. There are external GPUs (eGPU) available, but I have no experience if they would connect to the Dell XPS 13 and if they work under Ubuntu.
I went back to my previous editor (Shotcut), which does most of what I need.

Comment: I use OpenShot now and Lightworks. This is amazingly that DaVinci Resolve works on any device but... with Windows. Maybe you're right.  I give up with Resolve.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I'm getting to the splash screen now. Before I was getting nothing.