# DaVinci Resolve won't open after installation

Tags: software-installation

So I installed DaVinci resolve 15.2.2 from the official website by clicking on the Linux version and when I try to open it, it doesn't. I click on the app and then nothing happens. Plz help I don't want to switch back to MacOS it was a laggy OS. Also, I dont really know about terminal and how it could help in this situation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you share some more info? How did you install it? Can you run it from the terminal? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1108241/edit) your question with the added details.

Comment: You need a PC with a GPU:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058598/davinci-resolve-15-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04